# Reference my own nuget package: Can I avoid modifying all my csproj on each package update?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have created a "god repository" (let's call it G) which concentrates key features used by other parts of my app.

Since this repo is critical and shared accross multiple other components, I want to keep it isolated.

This repository produces a nuget package that is referenced by other solutions (in other repos X,Y,Z), and which version is automatically incremented by my build server.

Since G is still at an early development stage (not fully stable), it changes a lot.

**My issue:** With this scenario, I must update dozens of .csprojs in X,Y,Z each time a bugfix is pushed to G.

**My question:** Is there a way to avoid modifying csprojs (and packages.config) to update reference ? (e.g. to tell nuget that I want to reference the "latest" version of this package)
... I guess that this would lead to a HintPath that does not include package version.

Has someone experienced this kind of scenario ? Any workaround ?

Comment: Check this http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Answer (score 0):

If you have automatic restore enabled, which it is by default, as I recall, you shouldn't need to touch any other project once you add a NuGet package from anybody (including yourself). The next time the project is built, the NuGet Package Manager checks the NuGet repository, and it should automatically update the package in that project or solution.